# Terminating app due to uncaught exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I need some help, when I start app on **iphone 6** it starts but errors in console:

> 2015-06-05 12:45:45.211 EyeScanner[13508:189126] Failed to set (selectedImage) user defined inspected property on (HMNavigationController): [ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key selectedImage.
>   2015-06-05 12:45:45.213 EyeScanner[13508:189126] -[__NSCFNumber _imageThatSuppressesAccessibilityHairlineThickening]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000003
>   2015-06-05 12:45:45.213 EyeScanner[13508:189126] Failed to set (selectedImage) user defined inspected property on (UITabBarItem): -[__NSCFNumber _imageThatSuppressesAccessibilityHairlineThickening]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000003

But when I start it on **iphone 5s** with **IOS 7** - crash and log:

> 2015-06-05 13:50:57.202 EyeScanner[13752:607] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key selectedImage.'

Comment: check the property you have connected between your image view & class

Comment: click on view controller and check the outlets.....something is invalid there

Comment: Have you even find solution for this? @pluck

Comment: it was long time ago, but i fix it, i think it was coz of segue on navigation ctrl, something about this, i've changed segue on view ctrl, or call it programmatically, sorry not sure. And u need to remove outlets which set on storyboard but removed in code

Answer (score 0):

Here is the error:

`(HMNavigationController): [ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:` this class is `not key value coding-compliant` for the key `selectedImage`.

Check:

1- If you have connected the correct property with the object in `IBOutlet`.

2- Any deleted property in code, but object in `IBOutlet` still targeting that deleted property.

EDIT:

Try cleaning the project with Shift-Cmd-K

Also Clean Build Folder. To access the option open the Product menu and use the Option key to show the Clean Build Folder option.

[image: Xcode Image]

Comment: Can you show the controller screenshot, showing its connected properties.

Comment: I have >10 controllers, no warnings there, i have no idea why app crash

Comment: Can you show the outlets of this specific controller, because the issue is with the connections from `IBOutlet` to your properties defined in `HMNavigationController` interface.

Comment: This screenshot is for `HMStartNavigationCtrl` and the error you are getting is `HMNavigationController`. Also we need to see your interface for `HMNavigationController`

Comment: http://www.pictureshack.ru/images/67236_Snimok_ekrana_2015-06-05_v_14_52_45.png
h. file is empty

Comment: still don't understand why app crash only in ios 7, ios 8 show erros but still working

Comment: What exactly you do when app crashes like, when you click the button for some action or navigation to another controller ?

Comment: i guess i done with that problem, but now there new http://www.pictureshack.ru/images/53618_Snimok_ekrana_2015-06-05_v_15_04_31.png

Comment: app crash on start on IOS 7, in 8 it didnt

Comment: can you paste the code in your question, which is being used for images deletion.

Comment: Sorry, i dont understand how do i fix other issues but now there new, lol 
 
  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'showAuth'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'